# Cannot use ibus on applications

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ibus

I'm trying to install **ibus**. I changed my environment variable **XMODIFIERS** to **ibus**, then I log out and login, the variable still the old one, its doesn't change. I tried **unset** it and **export** it again but it still the same. I'm new to Ubuntu so if there're something I need to know, please tell me. I'm very appreciate.

UPDATE: I can change **XMODIFIERS** with `im-config` but the ibus only works with the search bar, not working with the applications.

UPDATE_2: I want to use Vietnamese, I turned on the ibus but I'm only able to type Vietnamese on the search bar. When I change to any application like Text Editor, LibreOffice or Browsers,... I cannot type in Vietnamese.

Here is my output for 2 commands below:

```
env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'

GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT4_IM_MODULE=ibus
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus



ps aux | grep ibus

tristan+    1831  0.0  0.0   2888   964 ?        Ss   10:58   0:00 sh -c /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable $([ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "x11" ] && echo "--xim")
tristan+    1839  0.1  0.1 326544 12256 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 /usr/bin/ibus-daemon --panel disable
tristan+    1927  0.0  0.0 248852  7700 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
tristan+    1931  0.8  0.3 359612 30252 ?        Sl   10:58   0:04 /usr/libexec/ibus-extension-gtk3
tristan+    1937  0.0  0.0 248780  7784 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-portal
tristan+    2117  0.5  0.1 1300968 9560 ?        Sl   10:58   0:02 /usr/lib/ibus-bamboo/ibus-engine-bamboo --ibus
tristan+    2318  0.0  0.3 206432 24664 ?        Sl   10:58   0:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-x11
tristan+    5896  0.0  0.0  20740  2664 pts/0    S+   11:07   0:00 grep --color=auto ibus
```

Here is my information:

- My Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 TLS
- Desktop environment: GNOME
- I've tried typing on: Chrome, Firefox, Brave, LibreOffice, TextEditor
- Package: I downloaded ibus with this git repository: https://github.com/BambooEngine/ibus-bamboo#c%C3%A0i-%C4%91%E1%BA%B7t-t%E1%BB%AB-openbuildservice

Comment: Actually, since you are on a GNOME DE, `im-config` does not really do anything. GNOME starts ibus and sets the variables. Anyway, I'm also on Ubuntu 22.04, and I don't see any issues with using ibus plugins. It would be good if you could edit your question again and be very specific about the remaining issues you see. Also, please show us the output from these terminal commands: 1. `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'` 2. `ps aux | grep ibus`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've updated the question. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I don't like all those input method related variables. How do you set those? If you stop setting them, GNOME will set `XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus` and `QT_IM_MODULE=ibus` only. The rest should not be there, especially not `GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus` since you are in Wayland sessions.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Oh, I followed the instruction of git author when wasn't able to use ibus. I will check it again. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information, so I'm going to guess a bit.

On an Ubuntu system you should use im-config to deal with `XMODIFIERS` and other environment variables which need to be set for ibus. If you have installed ibus, and "something" still changes `XMODIFIERS` to something else but `@im=ibus`, the explanation might be that you also have fcitx5 installed and run with some Asian locale.

In that case you can run the `im-config` command in a terminal window and explicitly tell it to configure **ibus** for your user. Then reboot.

im-config should both start ibus and set the necessary environment variables at login. So you shouldn't need to bother with those things manually.

Comment: Oh, that's convenient. But I wonder why I'm not able to use ibus in browsers, system search is works but browsers is not.

Comment: @nghia_pham: How would anybody be able to help you figure out that if you don't provide any details? As a starter, please edit you question and tell us which Ubuntu version and desktop environment you are on and which browsers you are tallking about. As regards the latter it may also be good to know the package format (.deb file, snap, flatpak, other).

Comment: Sorry for not giving any information. I've updated the question.